# Random.org for using dice in PHP Project

Tags: php, random

I'm a beginner and A need of my PHP Project is to roll a dice and generate random number using Random.org!

Normally I can generate number as:

rand(1,6);

But How i can include Random.org? Any references or tutorials will be appreciated :)

Comment: The first search on google for `random.org php api` yielded this result: https://www.random.org/clients/http/archive/ Where I'm sure you can find something to work with...

Comment: Why do you need to use random.org?

Comment: he wants a true-random number generator instead of a pseudo rng

Comment: mt_rand() is a pretty good pseudo-rng function for php, much better than the rand() function

Comment: @mramma I understand that he prefers true-randomness instead of pseudo-randomness, the question is why such a preference.

Comment: Its a part of php game project for true random number genrator within symfony framework. Thanks Richard for the archives...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include Random.Org's truly random number generator, you will need to use the API they provide.

https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/

It's free (As in public Beta) till Jan 31st 2015, after this there will be charges.